# How do I name a room in a logistics hub where some goods are being accepted for storage and some goods are subjected to the "sending" procedure?

Tags: phrase-requests, translation

How would one call a room in a warehouse where some goods are accepted for storage and some goods are "shipped away" to the customer? Would **"room for the acceptance and shipment (shipping) of goods**" fit?

The Russian phrase is

> • Помещение для проведения приёмки и отгрузки товара;

(from a list of logistics hub design requirements)

I always have trouble translating the Russian term "**отгрузка**" = "withdrawing of something out from storage and placement of it into a transportation vehicle in order to be directed to the customer/client". I'm unsure whether the word "shipping/shipment" really corresponds precisely to the Russian word.

The Russian word does not imply the actual process of transportation, only this initial bit of getting the goods out of storage, filling the necessary papers, and placement of the goods into vehicles, maybe owned by another firm, some third-party transportation company.

Maybe "dispatch of goods" would correspond, but is it really used? It looks and sounds odd. "Sending away of goods" is simplistic. Hm... "Room for the acceptance and sending of goods".. I dunno.

Comment: The intention of the room is unclear. A room is closed or has limited access through doors. In a warehouse, are you sure you're not talking about an area of the warehouse where these goods are placed? Also, is this room (or area) a place to put goods temporarily for a an hour or a day as one stage/one planned part of a longer shipping process, or for a few weeks until requested by some other independent process?

Comment: The term I've heard of used in this way in the retail context before was 'cage', basically a large static lockable area where goods were placed that were either being stored, or awaiting dispatch onward. This only applied to higher value goods, and the 'cage' was locked, with only senior staff having access to the keys: https://www.securitycagesdirect.co.uk/industry/retail/ while not tecnically a room it acted as one, as it was built into the mezzanine floor.

Comment: @Mitch - yes, you can call it "area" or "premise". Some goods arrive there from the "outer world" and undergo the "acceptance procedure" before being moved into the actual storage rooms. Other goods undergo the "shipping away" procedure, after which they are "on their way" to the client/customer. Maybe one could call it "handling and documentation area for incoming/outgoing goods"

Comment: 'receiving area' which is probably near the 'loading dock', if the shipping vehicles (trucks, trains, container ships) are dropping off things. But it sounds like you might want the name of the area for packages/pallets/containers to be placed _before_ they're put on the vehicles for transportation. Which one is it, the place after dropping things off, or the place for before they are shipped?

Comment: @Mitch - in this room, some goods undergo acceptance for storage, other goods undergo "sending away".

Comment: If it really is a "room" you could call it ["the transit room"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+transit+room%22) (about 6310 hits in Google Books), but you might also consider ["the transit **area**"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+transit+area%22) (about 6730 hits).

Comment: CowperKettle: hm... a lot of questions like these are best answered by people who are actually _there_. But I'd add to @FumbleFingers suggestion 'staging area', which could work for both incoming and outgoing packages.

Comment: Sounds like *Holding Area*.

Answer (score 2):

> Shipping and Receiving Facility

I think *shipping* fits your definition of the "withdrawing of something out from storage and placement of it into a transportation vehicle in order to be directed to the customer/client." That's why the *shipping date* is always the date at which items are loaded onto the delivery vehicle for transport. When we are talking about the actual transit of the items and their arrival at a destination, we use the terms *delivery estimate* and *delivery date* respectively.